# Cocoapods Integration Issues with xcode 8

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, ios10

I've been trying to use Cocoapods and https://github.com/opalorange/OpalImagePicker's function to integrate into my project.

However, I'd always have errors like 'No such module 'OpalImagePicker'' or 'Class is unavailable, cannot find Swift declaration for this module.

I made the integration worked somehow (once) but it's back to the errors right now.

What I did was just to change the scheme of my project to the OpalImagePicker module and run it until it's successful and go back to my project and clean+build and keep deleting and adding the framework from 'Link Binary with Libraries', clean+build.

Did anyone encounter such problems during integration of Cocoapods?

Updated with Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BPMatters' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BPMatters
pod 'OpalImagePicker'

  target 'BPMattersTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
pod 'OpalImagePicker'
  end

  target 'BPMattersUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
pod 'OpalImagePicker'
  end

end
```

Update with error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Something wrong with how you are configured your Podfile. Can you post it, so that we can take a look. Also, there are so many questions which answers how to solve `No such module 'XXX'`, might not be your framework. Go through it, it may give you some idea on how to solve this.

Comment: I've updated my question with the podfile. I've been researching about 'No such module XXX' and tried all ways but it's not working so far :\

Comment: Make sure you are opening .xcworkspace and not .xcodeproj file.

Comment: @digit yup i'm using .xcworkspace

Comment: Move the `pod OpalImagePicker` to the end and remove it from the all targets.

Comment: Why do you want `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. Since you are already using `OpalImagePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Podfile and add your pod just below the line use_frameworks!

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BPMatters' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BPMatters
  pod 'OpalImagePicker'

  target 'BPMattersTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'BPMattersUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Make sure to close your project in XCode and open it by double clicking the BPMatters.xcworkspace file.